# Open jars with Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, button

Hello so ive made an updater recently and my players can open the jar fine if I send them it directly and they click it directly

But if I ask them to use the button it wont load up for them this is what i have so far and the attempts i made

```
 if(OSCheck.isWindows()) {
     statusLabel.setText("Windows");
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", myClient);
     Process p = pb.start();
 } else if(OSCheck.isMac())  {
     statusLabel.setText("Mac");
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("#!/bin/sh java", "-jar", myClient);
     Process p = pb.start();
 }
```

As you can see I have it so it checks the OS the user is on and that works fine and then I made it so it says the OS They are on now in windows it works perfect no issues but I can not get it to open if they are using a mac as you can see i did make an attempt but did not work sadly

Comment: What is `#!/bin/sh java` supposed to do?

Comment: it is normaly what you add into the sh file like a .bat command it was just a bad guess really coz im completely clueless in this situation

Comment: But you're not writing a shell script here. The `ProcessBuilder` executes the command directly. And most certainly, there is no program named `#!/bin/sh java`. I think you don't need that whole OS probing here (btw there's more than Windows and Mac). Just execute `java` as you do for the WIndows case.

Comment: yeh i know that and it wont work for me when i do that the ProcessBuilder  only works in windows

Comment: ok so it works in eclipse on a mac and opens right but wont open it once its been jared

Comment: @5gon12eder `#!/bin/sh java` wouldn't be a program at all, it's a one-line comment

Comment: @cricket_007 If it were passed to a shell, it would be treated as a comment. But it isn't passed to a shell. As awkward as it is, you can actually have a file named `#!`.

Comment: I would like to add that there is no much sense in calling a Java application from a Java application. You should be able to simply run your app natively from with whatever this wrapper is supposed to do, eliminating any need for dependent processes, let alone OS detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [Jar Bundler](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html) to convert your .jars files to native .app executables for Mac OS X before execution it in your code.
If that is not an option, did you consider creating a shell script in terminal to execute the .jar for you?

Just thought about it a little bit and came up with another idear:

```
String cmd = "java -jar test.jar";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

EDIT:
Just came across this : [Jar launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jar_Launcher). Looks like a definite solution of you problem to me.

Hope I could help a little.